# Teradata dbc.columnsV

Tags: teradata

I had written a script which basically generates TPT dynamically by getting the column names from dbc.columnV and then using that TPT, I export that file to Hive. So in order to do this, the order of columns in TD and Hive must be same. I had previously created the DDL in Hive, based on the order of columns that were fetched from DBC.columnsV, but suddenly the order in my TPT has changed. Is it possible that the order of columns in DBC.columnsV changes due to some reason?

Comment: Did you include an `ORDER BY` when querying for column names? If not, the order can change from one execution to another. Typically you want to `ORDER BY ColumnId`.

Comment: To put it another way, the ordering of rows in the resultset from columns doesn't have any direct relationship to the physical order of columns in the table.

Comment: @Fred order by is one fix that I have now done for the future, but my question is that why did the order of columns suddenly change? This script was running from previous 5-6 months and not even once, the order changed...but now it changed all of a sudden?

Comment: @Andrew but why did the ordering of rows in resultset from dbc.columns, suddenly change now for the same query that has been running since months..

Comment: Select with no order by is by definition unordered, the order is not guaranteed. Theoretically, you could run the same query with no order by 10 times, and get a different sort every time.  Very unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Why did the ordering not change more often? Because dictionary tables are usually cached in memory. Unless one of the AMPs (units of parallelism within the database) is unusually busy with other work, they all respond "at once" and the actual sequence in which rows are merged back to the client depends on static "tie break" logic. If you query large tables that require physical I/O, you are likely to see the ordering vary much more often.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation, I guess caching was the reason for the order not changing  very often. The cache must have been cleared resulting in the change. Besides, I should have used `ORDER BY` in the first place, so that explains a lot. Cheers!